# Просканировать доступные сервера в локальной сети C++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно сделать программу которая в зависимости от выбора пользователя становится сервером либо клиентом на сокетах winsock2. Так вот, когда запущена одна программа в режиме сервера и еще одна например так же, и есть одна в режиме клиента, можно ли в клиентской части вывести список доступных серверов? Я не сильно разбираюсь в этой теме, но я так понимаю что нужно запустить эти сервера на разных портах, а затем на клиентской части перебрать все порты и к тем что можно подключится, вывести на экран. Я правильно думаю?

Comment: Серверы запускаются на одной машине или на разных?

Comment: На разных, но в одной сети вай-фай.

Comment: В принципе я еще подумал и придумал это: в программе будет 10 портов, например 1000 ,1001 и т.д. Клиент будет сканировать их подключаясь к каждому, если подключение произошло, сервер отправляет ключ(всегда одинаковый), клиент проверяет и если есть сходство то записываем порт в список, если нет, просто идем дальше. Нормальная идея?

Comment: Вообще-то, обычно сервера идентифицируют по IP-адресам, а открытые порты у них могут быть и одинаковые: например `192.168.0.1:1000`, `192.168.0.2:1000`. А для поиска сервера обычно выполняют широковещательный запрос (`SO_BROADCAST`), услышавшие сервера отвечают на него.

Comment: Понял, хорошая информация.